# How to use serial port from another class in C#?

Tags: c#, class, methods, serial-port

When I start the method "SendHex()" from my second class it gives me an error (port closed). While I can open the port from the main class and send any data successfully, but I can't do that from the second class!

This is my main class: (Edited)

```
namespace SerialPort
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (String s in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
            {
                txtPort.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }

        public System.IO.Ports.SerialPort SP = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
        public void serialport_connect(String port, int baudrate, Parity parity, int databits, StopBits stopbits)
        {
            SP = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(port, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits);
            try{ SP.Open();}
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error"); }
        }


        private void cmdConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String port = txtPort.Text;
            int baudrate = Convert.ToInt32(cmbbaudrate.Text);
            Parity parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cmbparity.Text);
            int databits = Convert.ToInt32(cmbdatabits.Text);
            StopBits stopbits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cmbstopbits.Text);
            serialport_connect(port, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits);
        }

        static byte[] HexToBytes(string input)
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[input.Length / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(2 * i, 2), 16);
            }
            return result;
        }

        public void SendHex(string hexData)
        {
            SP.Write(HexToBytes(hexData), 0, HexToBytes(hexData).Length);
        }
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SendCommand ss = new SendCommand();
            ss.SC();
        }


    }
}
```

And here is my second class:
Edited:

```
    namespace SerialPort
{
    class SendCommand
    {
        Form1 fm = new Form1();
        public void SC ()
            {
            String port = "COM30";
            int baudrate = Convert.ToInt32("115200");
            Parity parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), "None");
            int databits = Convert.ToInt32("8");
            StopBits stopbits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), "One");

            if (fm.SP.IsOpen)
            {
            }else

            {
                fm.serialport_connect(port, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits);
            }         
            fm.SendHex("aabb");
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: in seoncd class you should call serialport_connect method before sendhex

Answer (score 0):

In Second Class, you are creating a new Form object so your SerialPort is not open.
You may want to call SerialPort_Connect method before calling SendHex method.

SideNote: It would be nice if you move the SerialPort related code in seperate class and use that class in form as well as second class.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't manage to make it work, I added fm.serialport_connect(port, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits); after define the arguments values, but still say port is close! can you please write ore details?

Comment: I updated the codes, when I click on the button the port open and the data (hex) sent successfully but when I click it again it is said port closed?

Comment: @Majidff In your `serialport_connect` method you create a new instance of `SerialPort`. But you don't close the old instance. Since in C#, something that goes out of scope does not immediately go away, the old connection is still lingering. You can only connect to the same COM-port once, and so the second `SerialPort` instance cannot connect. Hence, port closed.

Comment: I want the port always open because I am also waiting data some coming from time to time. so I want to send data through the serial port from another class while it is open and used by the main class, is that possible?

Comment: @Majidff Sure, just pass the connected instance of `SerialPort` around.

Comment: I removed " SP = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(port, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits);" and added "SP.PortName = port; SP.BaudRate = baudrate; SP.Parity = parity;SP.DataBits = databits;SP.StopBits = stopbits;" but still same problem!

Comment: Read about Singleton pattern and how to use in application that should solve your problem....